# Trying to find dates for cabinet cards with Brooklyn business information and addresses?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, new-york-city, photo-identification, photo-dating

We have 2 cabinet cards and a cabinet-card-esque photograph that I believe are from the early 1900s that we are trying to date more concretely based on writing on the three cards.

- The first image has a label "F. Bertini Photo Booth" at the address "152 Stone Ave. Cor. Atlantic Ave., East N.Y. Brooklyn". This is definitely a cabinet card.
- The second image has a label reading "Gabinetto Portrait" with a small sun image with the phrase "sole ed arte" (sun art?) around it. This is also a cabinet card.
- The third image might be a cabinet card, but it is somewhat thinner than the others. It has a raised stamp on it with the address "673 Liberty Ave., Brooklyn, N.Y." and the name and/or business "T. Natoli"

I've checked a few business directories from 1900-1910, but there don't seem to be many from the 1910s (looking specifically 1912 to 1918, since we believe the subjects immigrated in 1912). Plus, the directories at Archive.org and NYPL Digital Collections are a little hard to read.